# After importing a module, when can you use the function without dot notation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import

Maybe I'm missing something really basic in Python. But if I:

```
import math
```

why do I have to do `math.sqrt(4)` to return 2.0, and I can't just do `sqrt(4)`?

I recall seeing in some place that it was possible to just call the functions from a module without using dot notation. Isn't it a given that, if the math module introduces `sqrt` as a function, I should be able to just do `sqrt(4)` instead of `math.sqrt(4)`?

Is it because the writers of the `math` module didn't make `sqrt` a function (like `def sqrt`), so I can't use it alone?

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
from math import sqrt    # recommended

sqrt(2)
```

This makes the function `sqrt` from the `math` module available in the current namespace.

Or:

```
from math import *

sqrt(2)
```

This makes all importable(*) functions and classes from the `math` module available in the current namespace; it is convenient, but creates a risk of cluttering the namespace and creating collisions.

You can [read about namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) to further your understanding.

---

(*) From @gilch in the comments:

> the `*` doesn't necessarily import everything. Normally, names that start with `_` are considered "private" and don't get imported with `*`. Or if the module has an `__all__` defined that can change what the `*` means.