# how to manage file for import in Python?

Tags: python

I want to get a common library from several files.
In order to reduce the amount of code, I want to create and manage a separate file for import.
Will it be possible?

import_lib.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
```

other_1.py

```
import import_lib

render()
get_object_or_404()
```

other_2.py

```
import import_lib

render()
get_object_or_404()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After importing a module, When can you use the function without dot notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58177829/after-importing-a-module-when-can-you-use-the-function-without-dot-notation)

Comment: I know that if I want to use the render() like the url you added, I have to use it like import_lib.render().
But I want to know if there is a way to subordinate. Here's an example of Django's grammar.  {% include import_lib.py %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to hide the imports needed in your module in another module - it'll make your code harder to read. And good editors will allow you to collapse the import section if it gets in the way of editing. There's ways of doing this, but they'll make your code harder to understand and it'll increase the odds of errors that are hard to figure out for yourself.

Having said that - this is how it can be done, if for some reason you know better, or actually have that rare use case where it makes sense:

import_lib.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
```

other.py

```
from import_lib.py import *  # a rare case where a * import actually makes sense
```

Since `*` imports everything and makes it part of the name space of the module doing the importing, you get exactly what you need.

If you feel your use case does warrant this, at least consider a name for the imported module that's a bit more descriptive, like `django_imports.py`, or whatever the logical grouping for the imports in that file is.

Comment: Thank you. If I want to cooperate with others, I shouldn't hide it